# linphone sdk macOS registration not working

Tags: flutter, linphone

I send registration request in linphone sdk on macOS, but I do not receive response for register in onAccountRegistrationStateChanged method and linphone is not registered.
There are no errors in the Linphone log.

linphone sdk version: 5.2.86

macOS: 13.3.1

logs:
2023-07-07 17:17:28:882 liblinphone-message-LinphoneAccount[0x14cf515b8] created with params
2023-07-07 17:17:28:882 liblinphone-message-linphone_core_find_auth_info(): returning auth info username=111, realm=
2023-07-07 17:17:28:882 liblinphone-message-linphoneAccountIsServerConfigChanged : 0
2023-07-07 17:17:28:882 liblinphone-message-Publish params have changed on account [0x14cf515b8]
2023-07-07 17:17:28:882 liblinphone-message-Invalidating friends maps for list [0x6000021870c0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the logs, do you see the REGISTER being sent to your server?

If not, make sure you have called core.start() after creating/configuring it, and that you periodically call core.iterate() method.